# ModuleError: No module name lxml

Tags: python

I am trying to run this code:

```
python labelImg.py
```

but I keep getting the same error:

```
   C:\Users\Bakang\labelImg>python labelImg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bakang\labelImg\labelImg.py", line 40, in <module>
    from libs.labelFile import LabelFile, LabelFileError, LabelFileFormat
  File "C:\Users\Bakang\labelImg\libs\labelFile.py", line 13, in <module>
    from libs.pascal_voc_io import PascalVocWriter
  File "C:\Users\Bakang\labelImg\libs\pascal_voc_io.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

but I gave already run these codes in jupyter notebook:

```
    !pip install pyqt5 lxml --upgrade
!cd labelImg && pyrcc5 -o libs/resources.py resources.qrc
```

Comment: A couple things about the code you show at the bottom. First.. Use of the exclamation point with `pip install` is outdated. `%pip install <package name>` is the current best practice, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic commands `%pip install` and `%conda install` that insure that the installation occurs in the environment backing the notebook. Use of an exclamation point alone doesn't do this. ...

Comment: <continued> More about the deficiency in the exclamation point approach in the top two paragraphs [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez).  Second, I cannot tell if your `!cd` command is going to work as you wish or not. I'm not sure what you are trying to do in that line. If you want the working directory to change in the notebook namespace, you want `%cd`, see [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd). What you are doing may be fine if only need it changed for that line.

Comment: Also within a Jupyter notebook, you want to use `%run labelImg.py`. It is more full featured than `!python labelImg.py`. See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) about `%run` that connects better to the notebook and includes more options. (Occasionally, you do want to use `!python <script.py>` in a notebook when illustrating something or trying to specifically channel output or errors.) And if you are running `python labelImg.py` in a terminal you want to run your pip install command in that terminal and not in the Jupyter notebook you mention.